# Mapping Animal distribution data?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1

I have downloaded CSV occurrence datasets for voles and kestrels in the UK, then displayed the XY data of each as points using the latitude and longitude. Not sure if this is the right place to post but I have a few queries

1. Is there any way to remove certain points? They are very large datasets and I only wish to investigate England and Wales - although I have data for Scotland and Northern Ireland as well. I could only come up with a painstakingly slow method of trawling through 10,000 odd points based on their co-ordinates. Can I somehow delete the XY data points?
2. Is there a better way to depict the populations other than clumps of dots?
3. Is there anything cool I can do with the data? (it's for an assignment - we've barely been taught GIS and I would like to get cheeky extra marks) I added locations of SSSI's (highest level of British protected areas) in England and Wales to the maps. Could I do some sort of analysis based upon that?

I am using esri arcgis 10.1

Comment: Shouldn't we be the ones to get the extra marks if we give you ideas? You should try finding a correlation between the data you have and other data you can get your hands on. Think like human population, pollution, terrain type, election results.

Comment: 1) Join the points attributes with a country/region shape and then select your desired points 2) build a heatmap, google for it 3) Of course you could do a lot of nice analysis, but can you do it? I can, but i am not solving your homework for you.

Comment: Use the Intersect tool with boundary data (country, SSSI from English Nature). You will reduce your dataset using this tool. http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000000p000000

Answer (score 2):

First you're going to need to create an [ESRI Global Account](https://webaccounts.esri.com/CAS/index.cfm?fuseaction=Registration.ShowForm&ReturnURL=http://training.esri.com/gateway/index.cfm?fa=myTraining.gateway&FailURL=http://training.esri.com/gateway/index.cfm?fa=myTraining.gateway&e=t&appId=TS47YY90P3CX1). Once you create an account you can learn the basics of ArcGIS through the [free lessons](http://training.esri.com/gateway/index.cfm?fa=search.results&cannedsearch=2). Since you have no formal training that is where I would start.
I would start with this [getting started](http://training.esri.com/gateway/index.cfm?fa=catalog.webCourseDetail&courseid=2500),  [lesson on editing](http://training.esri.com/gateway/index.cfm?fa=catalog.webCourseDetail&courseid=1910)

These lessons will help you better understand GIS. I could tell you what to do in order to get the result you want - but it's no use for your homework if you don't know what you did.

In order to remove points you need to be in an "editing session". If you have access to polygons or boundaries of the UK you can make selections based on what points you want --

Look into "select by location". From there you can export your selection (which would be the points in Wales and England).

As for extra points - perhaps doing some statistical analysis on which points fall in protected zones, compare wales to england, etc.